# Update algorithm to save memory: find one solution instead of finding all the solutions then pick one

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, select, backtracking

Given the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int num = 4;
        final int finalCount = 8;
        int[][] idArr = new int[num][];
        int[][] typeArr = new int[num][];
        int[][] countArr = new int[num][];


        idArr = new int[][]{
                {1001, 2001, 3001, 4001},
                {5001, 6001, 7001},
                {2002, 3002, 5002, 8001},
                {9001},
        };

        typeArr = new int[][]{
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {5, 6, 7,},
                {2, 3, 5, 8},
                {9},
        };

        countArr = new int[][]{
                {3},
                {1, 2},
                {2},
                {1},
        };

    }
}
```

demands:

find a solution: select `x` elements from idArr, `x = sum(countArr[i][0]) <= finalCount, (0 <= i <countArr.length)`, solution must:

1. solution elements contains `y` elements in each `idArr[i]`, `y` >= `countArr[i][0]` and <= `count[i][1]` if `countArr[i][1]` exists;
2. solution elements are distinct in types(types are related to typeArr)

I know one solution with my brain:

```
1001,2001,3001,
6001,
5002,8001,
9001
```

because:

1. the solution has 7 elements, which <= finalCount;
2. arr[0] has `1001,2001,3001` selected, and their size >=  `3` related to countArr[0];
3. arr[1] has `6001` selected, its size = 1, match the demand of `1 <= size <=2` in countArr[1];
4. arr[2] has `5002,8001` selected, its size = 2, match the demand of `size >= 2` in countArr[2];
5. arr[3] has `9001` selected, its size = 1, match the demand of `size >= 1` in countArr[3];
6. each arr[i] has element(s) in the slected elements, and the selected elements match the condition: 2&3&4&5.
7. elements are differ in type related in typArr.

I used backtracking to solve it. Find all solutions and pick one. Apparently this kind of approach costs memory much. So I'm seeking an algorithm that just find a solution without finding all the solutions.

Could someone give me a better solution to reference?

---

My Solution:

```
public class Test4SO {
    private static int[][] idArr;
    private static int[][] countArr;
    private static int[][] typeArr;
    /**
     * the selected elements must not exceeds this number
     */
    private static final int finalCount = 8;
    /**
     * the count of idArr.length
     */
    private static final int num = 4;

    private static final Map<Integer, Integer> idTypeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // case 1
        idArr = new int[][]{
                {1001, 2001, 3001, 4001},
                {5001, 6001, 7001},
                {2002, 3002, 5002, 8001},
                {9001},
        };

        typeArr = new int[][]{
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {5, 6, 7,},
                {2, 3, 5, 8},
                {9},
        };

        countArr = new int[][]{
                {3},
                {1, 2},
                {2},
                {1},
        };

        // case 2
//        idArr = new int[][]{
//                {1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 1005},
//                {2001, 3001, 1003},
//                {3001, 4001, 1005, 5002},
//                {4001, 1003},
//        };
//
//        typeArr = new int[][]{
//                {1, 2, 3, 4,1},
//                {2, 3, 1},
//                {3, 4, 1, 5},
//                {4, 1},
//        };
//
//        countArr = new int[][]{
//                {3},
//                {1, 2},
//                {2},
//                {1},
//        };

        // case 3
//        idArr = new int[][]{
//                {1001},
//                {2001},
//                {3001},
//                {1001, 2001, 3001, 4001, 5001},
//        };
//
//        typeArr = new int[][]{
//                {1},
//                {2},
//                {3},
//                {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
//        };
//
//        countArr = new int[][]{
//                {1},
//                {1},
//                {1},
//                {5},
//        };

        // for each id, put its type into the map as a cache
        for (int i = 0; i < idArr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < idArr[i].length; j++) {
                idTypeMap.put(idArr[i][j], typeArr[i][j]);
            }
        }

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        // see introduction a
        int[][][] arr = new int[idArr.length][0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < idArr.length; i++) {
            int min = countArr[i][0];
            int max = countArr[i].length > 1 ? countArr[i][1] : finalCount;
            List<int[]> combinationList = new ArrayList<>();
            // find all combinations of idArr[i] with the specified number from min to max
            for (int j = min; j <= max; j++) {
                int[][] combinationArr = getCombinationArr(idArr[i], j);
                combinationList.addAll(Arrays.asList(distinct(combinationArr)));
            }
            arr[i] = combinationList.toArray(new int[0][]);
        }

        
        List<Integer> result = backtrack(arr);
        System.out.println("time cost: " + stopwatch.stop());

        // print arr
        for (int[][] ints : arr) {
            for (int[] anInt : ints) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(anInt));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // final result
        System.out.println("final result: ");
        for (Integer id : result) {
            System.out.println(id);
        }

    }

    /**
     * get the combination of the specified number from the array, and the combination
     * does not contain duplicate elements. 
     */
    public static int[][] getCombinationArr(int[] arr, int num) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<>();
        dfs(arr, num, 0, combination, result);
        int[][] combinations = new int[result.size()][num];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
                combinations[i][j] = result.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }
        return combinations;
    }

    private static void dfs(int[] arr, int num, int start, List<Integer> combination, List<List<Integer>> result) {
        if (combination.size() == num) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(combination));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
            combination.add(arr[i]);
            dfs(arr, num, i + 1, combination, result);
            combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> backtrack(int[][][] arr) {
        List<List<Integer>> lists = backtrack(arr, 0, new ArrayList<>());

        System.out.println("all permutations: ");
        lists.stream().filter(list -> distinct(list) && list.size() <= finalCount).forEach(System.out::println);

        // see introduction c, d
        for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
            if (distinct(list) && list.size() <= finalCount) {
                return list;
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }


    /**
     * judge if the list(consists of id from idArr) distinct in types
     */
    public static boolean distinct(List<Integer> list) {
        List<Integer> typeList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer id : list) {
            if (typeList.contains(getTypeById(id))) {
                return false;
            }
            typeList.add(getTypeById(id));
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * remove combinations(consists of id from idArr) with duplicate types
     */
    public static int[][] distinct(int[][] arr) {
        List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int[] ints : arr) {
            List<Integer> typeList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int anInt : ints) {
                if (!typeList.contains(getTypeById(anInt))) {
                    typeList.add(getTypeById(anInt));
                }
            }
            if (typeList.size() == ints.length) {
                list.add(ints);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new int[0][]);
    }

    public static int getTypeById(int id) {
        return idTypeMap.get(id);
    }

    // see introduction b
    private static List<List<Integer>> backtrack(int[][][] arr, int index, List<Integer> current) {
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (index == arr.length) {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(current));
            return result;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr[index].length; i++) {
            List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[index][i].length; j++) {
                subList.add(arr[index][i][j]);
            }

            boolean b1 = new HashSet<>(current).containsAll(subList);
            boolean b2 = !current.isEmpty() && new HashSet<>(subList).containsAll(current);

            // for case 2
            if (!b1) {
                current.addAll(subList);
            }

            // for case 3
            if (b2) {
                current = subList;
            }
            result.addAll(backtrack(arr, index + 1, current));
            if (!b1) {
                current.removeAll(subList);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Introduction to my solution:

a. to create a 3d array to store all combinations of `arr[i]` with specified number from min to max in related `countArr`, for example, with finalCount=5:

```
      idArr = new int[][]{
                {1001, 2001, 3001},
                {5001, 6001， 2002},
         
        };

        typeArr = new int[][]{
                {1, 2, 3},
                {5, 6， 2}
        };

        countArr = new int[][]{
                {3},
                {1, 2},
    
        };
```

the 3d array: `arr3d` should be:

```
{
    {
        {1001,2001,3001}
    },
    {
        {5001}， {6001}， {2002}，{5001，6001}， {5001,2002}，{6001,2002}
    }
}
```

b. then in latter steps, I can loop the 3d array from `arr3d[0][j]` to `arr3d[arr3d.length - 1][j]` to find all combinations, for example:

```
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {5001} = {1001,2001,3001, 5001}
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {6001} = {1001,2001,3001, 6001}
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {2002} = {1001,2001,3001, 2002}
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {5001, 6001} = {1001,2001,3001, 5001, 6001}
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {5001, 2002} = {1001,2001,3001, 5001, 2002}
{1001, 2001, 3001} + {6001, 2002} = {1001,2001,3001, 6001, 2002}
```

c. then filter the list with duplicate type, for example:

```
before filter:
{1001,2001,3001, 5001}
{1001,2001,3001, 6001}
{1001,2001,3001, 2002}
{1001,2001,3001, 5001, 6001}
{1001,2001,3001, 5001, 2002}
{1001,2001,3001, 6001, 2002}

after filter:
{1001,2001,3001, 5001, 6001}
{1001,2001,3001, 5001}
{1001,2001,3001, 6001}
```

d. therefore, `{1001,2001,3001, 5001, 6001}`, `{1001,2001,3001, 5001}` and `{1001,2001,3001, 6001}` are filted out, and each size <= finalCount = 5, so they are valid solutions. Finally,I just pick one from the valid soutions.

Comment: You should state the problem clearer, I don't think many readers are willing to parse it from comments inside a code block referring to arrays by names that don't exist.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've updated the post again,  hope this will make my intention clearer.

Comment: Can you tell more constraints ? such as : `1 <= idArr.length <= 10^3, 1<= idArr[0].length <= 10^6`

Comment: Sure. Actually this is to select heros from backpack who math several conditions in a game. `idArr.length` is the count of the conditions, and `idArr[0].length` is the hero count that match the first condition. For example, in above `idArr`, I have 4(`idArr.length`) conditions, and for each condition, there're `arr[i].length` heros match it.

Comment: According to our design, we'll have 150 heros limit in our backpack,  which means `idArr[i].length` would no more than 150. And we'll select no more than 5(`finalCount`) heros that match all the conditions. The condition count, which is `idArr.length`, would no more than 4.

Comment: Please introduce your code with a description of what it is to accomplish.

Comment: So you want to choose heroes from several sets. Each set has a lower and an optional upper bound on the amount of heroes selected from it. Also there is an upper bound on the total amount of heroes selected. Also each hero has a type, and no more than a single hero of a type can be selected. Is this correct? Then it should be at the beginning of your question, I had to deduce it from (still incorrect) comments and the example solution.

Comment: Do you want to get a single solution (as your question states), or iterate over all solutions without storing them all in memory at the same time?

Comment: Yes, your deduction is right.And I want to get a single solution.

Comment: What is the range of `typeArr[i][j]` , can i assume that `typeArr[i][j]` not so big, like `1 <= typeArr[i][j] <= 10` ?

Comment: @Jesse  `typeArr[i][j]` ranges from 1 to 120.

Comment: Then why don't you perform checks on candidate solutions as soon as you generate them? You generate an array of possible solutions and filter them. Instead you can move all filtering operations inside the generation. Instead of placing maybe-a-solution in a huge array you can verify it immediately and if it is correct return it, otherwise keep searching.

Comment: I think the most optimal solution for your problem is maximum bipartite matching with constraints implemented through reduction to maximum flow. But it is much more complicated than just avoiding storing a huge list of maybe-solutions in RAM as I suggested in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused after reading your code.

### What's the real purpose of your program？

Base on your description below:

> find a solution:
> select x(x <= finalCount) elements from idArr, elements must:
>
> 1. elements in each idArr[i], their count must >= countArr[i][0] and <= count[i][1] if countArr[i][1] exists;
> 2. elements are differ in types(types are related to typeArr)

I think your solution would be like this(Based on your thinking):

> - a. Calculate the `selectedCount=sum(countArr[i][0])` `0<= i <countArr.length` , just a greedy method do not need to think about the `countArr[i][1]`, then the `x` is `selectedCount`.
> - b. Get all combinations( `List<int[]> combinationList` ) of idArr[i] with the countArr[i].
> - c. Use backtrack loop combinationList[i] merge each `current = combinationList[0][j] -> combinationList[1][j] ... -> combinationList[combinationList.size() - 1][j]` check if `current` valid or not, if `current` are valid then this is the correct solution, just return it.

You can just return the correct result `current` in `backtrack`, then the memory is all about `combinationList`.

### The real problem is the performance of `backtrack`

You should calculate the time complexity about `backtrack`.

According the constrains of your description below:

> - 1 <= idArr.length <= 4, 1 <= idArr[i].length <= 150
> - 1 <= typeArr[i] <= 120,1 <= typeArr.length <= 4, 1 <= idArr[i].length <= 150
> - 1 <= countArr.length <= 4, 1 <= countArr[i].length <= 2
> - 1 <= finalCount <= 8

Assume some test data for instance:

**idArr** : `idArr.length = 4` , `idArr[0].length = 100, idArr[1].length = 10, idArr[2].length = 10, idArr[3].length = 10`

**countArr** : `countArr = {{5},{1},{1},{1}}`

**finalCount** : `finalCount = 8`

[image]

Then the size of `combinationList[0]` will be `75,287,520` almost `7*10^7`, the size of `combinationList[1-3]` will be `10`, so the run times of `backtrack` is `7*10^10` , that is a big numble.

You should do some performance test, the description of this task(program) is so redundancy, i am not sure about the real purpose of your task(program).

Comment: Yes, your description is more clearer than mine.  As  @maxplus has said, I could  perform checks on candidate solutions as soon as I generate them. That is correct. And I've tried to do it.  But the improvement is not very significant and my program always be bothered with OOM. So your view of the performance of backtrack is absolutely right.  I don't think backtrack is a good solution to solve the problem.